# How to show tooltips on the QGroupBox title instead of its body

Tags: qt, pyqt, tooltip, qgroupbox

I tried to use setToolTip of QGroupBox, but the tooltip shows in all places in the group box. What I want is to only show the tooltip in the title label.

Is is even possible? If not, why the QGroupBox is designed that way?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to control the tool-tip behaviour, but there's no built-in method to do that, so you just need to add a little custom event-handling yourself. Here's a basic demo that implements that using an event-filter:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test')
        self.button.setToolTip('Button ToolTip')
        self.group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Title')
        self.group.installEventFilter(self)
        self.group.setToolTip('Groupbox ToolTip')
        self.group.setCheckable(True)
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.group)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.group)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ToolTip and
            isinstance(source, QtWidgets.QGroupBox)):
            options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGroupBox()
            source.initStyleOption(options)
            control = source.style().hitTestComplexControl(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox, options, event.pos())
            if (control != QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxLabel and
                control != QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxCheckBox):
                QtWidgets.QToolTip.hideText()
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

An alternative solution would be to create a subclass and override the `event` method directly:

```
class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ToolTip:
            options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGroupBox()
            self.initStyleOption(options)
            control = self.style().hitTestComplexControl(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox, options, event.pos())
            if (control != QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxLabel and
                control != QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxCheckBox):
                QtWidgets.QToolTip.hideText()
                return True
        return super().event(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`QWidget::setToolTip`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop), by defaults, set the tooltip for the whole widget. `QGroupBox` does not provide a special tooltip behavior, so the tooltip is visible for the whole group box, including its children (except if those provide their own tooltips). However, you are ably to customise this behaviour yourself, by reimplementing `QWidget::event`:

> If you want to control a tooltip's behavior, you can intercept the
> event() function and catch the QEvent::ToolTip event (e.g., if you
> want to customize the area for which the tooltip should be shown).

Two approaches are possible:

- Capture the `QEvent::ToolTip` event on the `QGroupBox` itself. See the comment of musicamante on how to determine the title region.
- Capture the `QEvent::ToolTip` on the children of the `QGroupBox` and suppress the the event.

A full blown [custom tooltip example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-tooltips-example.html) is given in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-tooltips-example.html) itself.

Comment: With the style's `subControlRect()` it should be quite easy, actually, since it's possible to use the `SC_GroupBoxLabel`.